# Expanding on the split() method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split

This is something that has been bothering me for a while.

Assume I'm doing this on a line

```
var result = "Noble warm and pretty darm Caesar.".split(/(\warm)/);
// ["Noble ", "warm", " and pretty ", "darm", " Caesar."]
```

Would it be possible to extend the split method in order to manipulate regexp catches with a function like `replace` does on strings?

Pseudo-code:

```
var result = "Noble warm and pretty darm Caesar.".split(/(\warm)/, function (match) {
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + match + '</span>';
});
// ["Noble ", "<span style=\"color:red;\">warm</span>", " and pretty ", "<span style=\"color:red;\">darm</span>", " Caesar."]
```

Comment: Well, you can create your own function which then iterates over the array and makes the replacements as necessary.

Comment: There's really nothing in JavaScript that can be described as "extending a method". You can write new code that uses `.split()` and then does more work.

Comment: @Pointy: Poor choice of words, I meant 'extending' in a more lightweight sense.

Comment: Right, and as Mr. Kling says you can certainly write code to do something to the elements of the array returned by `.split()`. Be aware that browsers aren't necessarily consistent with what's returned from `.split()` when you call it with a regex.

Comment: @Pointy: Perhaps I should actually modify a JavaScript implementation of the `.split()` method and use `String.prototype.splitNew`?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own function in the `prototype` object property of the `String` object.

The following function is an example of what you could do :

```
String.prototype.splitReplace = function(pattern, fn)
{
    var array = this.split(pattern);
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            array[i] = fn(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

As stated above, this function is just a quick example, to show how you could add a function to the String prototype property. But you should use the smart and robust function declaration @User2121315 gave us in the comments